# How to animate exoplayer2 controller view show and hide action?

Tags: android, exoplayer2.x

I have used exoplayer2 for showing videos in an android application. I have overridden `exo_player_controller_view.xml`. Everything is working fine now what I am trying to do is that animate the appearance to fade-in and disappearance to fade-out of the controller view exactly like YouTube does.

Can anyone help?

Thank you

Comment: and what kind of problems do you have with "fade" animation? whats your code you already wrote?

Comment: I could not apply any code for fade animation. I don't even know where to apply fade the animation code.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case if anyone still looking for solution, you can simply add

> `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"`

in `<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView>`. This provides the fade animation by default.